# How can I know status of a domain Registrar lock

Tags: dns, namecheap

When start a transfer in namecheap we can get domain Registrar lock.
[namecheap screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQFGX.png)
 
How can I get this information?
Using whois I can only get `clientTransferProhibited` 
Does it mean domain is locked?

```
Domain Name: google.com
Registry Domain ID: 2138514_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.markmonitor.com
Registrar URL: http://www.markmonitor.com
Updated Date: 2018-02-21T10:45:07-0800
Creation Date: 1997-09-15T00:00:00-0700
Registrar Registration Expiration Date: 2020-09-13T21:00:00-0700
Registrar: MarkMonitor, Inc.
Registrar IANA ID: 292
Registrar Abuse Contact Email: abusecomplaints@markmonitor.com
Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +1.2083895740
Domain Status: clientUpdateProhibited (https://www.icann.org/epp#clientUpdateProhibited)
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited (https://www.icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited)
Domain Status: clientDeleteProhibited (https://www.icann.org/epp#clientDeleteProhibited)
Domain Status: serverUpdateProhibited (https://www.icann.org/epp#serverUpdateProhibited)
Domain Status: serverTransferProhibited (https://www.icann.org/epp#serverTransferProhibited)
Domain Status: serverDeleteProhibited (https://www.icann.org/epp#serverDeleteProhibited)
Registrant Organization: Google LLC
Registrant State/Province: CA
Registrant Country: US
Admin Organization: Google LLC
Admin State/Province: CA
Admin Country: US
Tech Organization: Google LLC
Tech State/Province: CA
Tech Country: US
Name Server: ns1.google.com
Name Server: ns3.google.com
Name Server: ns4.google.com
Name Server: ns2.google.com
DNSSEC: unsigned
URL of the ICANN WHOIS Data Problem Reporting System: http://wdprs.internic.net/
```

Comment: This is offtopic as not related to programming. "Registrar Lock" is mostly a marketing term, not a technical one. You will need to refer to your registrar TOS. The EPP statuses `client*Prohibited` are indeed sign of some kind of protections at the registrar level, and same for the `server` ones that may be using some kind of `registry lock`. Your registrar should be able to explain all of that to you.

Comment: Also go to the URL you see in the whois output, the ICANN website will explains everything related to EPP statuses to you.